# file upload with attachment_fu in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, file-upload, attachment-fu

My file upload is working fine on IE.

But it's returning "406 not acceptable" error on firefox.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
before_filter :login_required, :except=>[:new, :create]
```